# Show that $(\overline A ∪ B) ∩ (\overline C - A) = (\overline C - A)$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

> Let $A, B,$ and $C$ be sets. Show that:
>   $$
> (\overline A ∪ B) ∩ (\overline C - A) = (\overline C - A)
> $$

I’ve simplified to the following: 
$$
(\overline A ∪ B) ∩ (\overline{C \cup A}) = (\overline{C \cup A})
$$
How would I simplify $\overline A ∪ B$?

Draw Venn diagrams for the expressions on both sides. So on the left I have circles for $A, B, C$ and on the right just $A, C$. Is it enough to say that they are equal since the shaded in area is everywhere but $A$ and $C$ on both (regardless of the $B$ that is shaded in on the left)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show that $X \cap Y = Y$, it suffices to show that $Y \subseteq X$. So all we need to do is prove that $\overline C - A \subseteq \overline A \cup B$. Indeed:
$$
\overline C - A
= \overline C \cap \overline A
\subseteq \overline A
\subseteq \overline A \cup B
$$